# why my screenshots have 0 bytes?

Tags: screenshot

I've worked for a couple of months with a computer that has Ubuntu as the operating system. Intermittently, when pressing the print screen button, some weird un-openable 0 bytes screenshots are created. When this happens, also other screenshots apps have problems. For example `shutter` (a screenshot app) says `there was an error saving the image to...` and, under `show more details`, there is `Fatal error in PNG image file: write error`.

The pattern in which this happens seems random; the only consistency is then, when it happens, screenshots have problems in both the apps.

Do you have any solution that I could try to solve this problem?

Comment: Technical details must be supplied to have any hope of a resolution.

Comment: "Write error" suggests looking at your logs during that period of time for other clues: Filesystem problems. I/O problems, etc.

Comment: Within 5 minutes of the event, the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --since="-5 minutes"` will show system logs that cover the event. Read `man journalctl`. Each log message starts with a timestamp, the host that issued the log entry, the process name, the PID in `[]` of the issuer and a colon (`:`). Everything after the colon is a message from the programmer, intended to help the user understand the program's behavior. Read `msn logger`.